# How to manage docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode, docker-cloud

I'm trying to set up a docker swarm, and then deploy to it from my local machine.

The swarm is up and running with 2 virtual machines, where one of them is manager, and the other is worker.

Though now i can't seem to deploy to the swarm..

When i right click the tray icon, swarm, and then connect to my named swarm.
Then when i try and deploy I get:

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_cloud_39dc8579-e4a3-4603-a078-dc3e204e7532/v1.30/info: open //./pipe/docker_cloud_39dc8579-e4a3-4603-a078-dc3e204e7532: Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet.
```

If I connect using normal commandprompt i get:

```
this node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again
```

Even though I've already used the connect-string from Docker Cloud.

Anyone have any clues to what I'm doing wrong?

**Image of the registration:**
[image]

Comment: I assume as you are running Windows. Have you run `docker swarm init` on your host machine? Like from Powershell.  You said you have the swarm up and running in two virtual machines but unless you make the host a swarm node, the host won't be counted as a swarm manager.

Comment: @ManoMarks I'm running Windows on my local machine, that's correct.  
I've on 1 of the virtual machines run `docker swarm init` and the other one have joined that managing node.

Am I supposed to be manager on my local machine?

Comment: Your local Docker for Windows doesn't know what's happening on the VMs unless you make it part of the swarm. So you won't be able to manage from the command line unless your swarm is registered in Cloud *and* you are logged in through Docker for Windows. Make sure you've followed all the steps in the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/cloud-swarm/register-swarms/

Comment: Updated question with an image, so you can see it has been registrered..